# How to print output of linked template using ARM template in Azure

Tags: azure, templates, azure-rm-template

I am using maintemplate and linked template for deployment. I want to print the output of linked template after deployment.

When I deploy the below template. I am getting the below error,

> The template output 'vmpublicIPName' is not valid: The language
>   expression property 'publicIPName' doesn't exist, available properties
>   are ''.. (Code: DeploymentOutputEvaluationFailed)

1. How can I print the output of variables present in linked template?
2. Is there any way to print all the linked template deployment parameters values in main template?

storage.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_LRS"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '1rmtest')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "accountType": "[parameters('storageAccountType')]"
            },
            "tags": {
                "BuildName": "StorageARM"
            }
        },
        { 
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01", 
            "name": "TestTemplate", 
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments", 
            "properties": { 
                "mode": "incremental", 
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri":"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/public-ip-template.json",
                    "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {                    
                    "publicIpAddressName": {
                        "value": "public-ip-test"
                    }
                }
            } 
        }

    ],
    "outputs": {
        "vmpublicIPName": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[reference('TestTemplate').outputs.publicIPName]"
        },
        "vmlocation": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[reference('TestTemplate').outputs.location]"
        }
    }
}
```

Linked template:-

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "publicIpAddressName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
            "apiVersion": "2016-09-01",
            "location": "[variables('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "publicIpAllocationMethod": "Static"
            }
        }  

    ],
    "outputs": {
        "publicIPName": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('location')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Walter-MSFT I have tried the above. Still I get same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you ensure your linked template URI is correct and accessible? According to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates)

> The URI value for the linked parameter file cannot be a local file,
>   and must include either http or https.

I test in my lab, I only replace your URI such as below:

```
 "templateLink": {
                    "uri":"https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/d5387c0fc92f2e8df1c7157a2d5e54aa/raw/722d4a58107b2f617996ae237ceae445ef4342d9/test.json",
                    "contentVersion":"1.0.0.0"
                },
```

Your template works for me.

[image]

> How can I print the output of variables present in linked template?

Yes, this is possible. Just like your template.

> Is there any way to print all the linked template deployment
>   parameters values in main template?

You could use Azure cli 2.0 to get linked parameter values.

```
az group deployment create --name shuitest1 --resource-group shuitest --template-file test.json --parameters '{"storageAccountName":{"value":"shuitest"}}'

{
  "id": "/subscriptions/********/resourceGroups/shuitest/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/shuitest1",
  "name": "shuitest1",
  "properties": {
    "correlationId": "dbe16f35-0807-4627-b4b5-86c0a25c49ba",
    "debugSetting": null,
    "dependencies": [],
    "mode": "Incremental",
    "outputs": {
      "vmlocation": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
          "type": "String",
          "value": "centralus"
        }
      },
      "vmpublicIPName": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": {
          "type": "String",
          "value": "public-ip-test"
        }
      }
    },
    "parameters": {
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "shuitest"
      },
      "storageAccountType": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "Standard_LRS"
      }
    },
    "parametersLink": null,
    "providers": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "namespace": "Microsoft.Storage",
        "registrationState": null,
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "locations": [
              "centralus"
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "storageAccounts"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": null,
        "namespace": "Microsoft.Resources",
        "registrationState": null,
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
            "aliases": null,
            "apiVersions": null,
            "locations": [
              null
            ],
            "properties": null,
            "resourceType": "deployments"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "template": null,
    "templateLink": null,
    "timestamp": "2017-04-19T02:09:55.064156+00:00"
  },
  "resourceGroup": "shuitest"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"someName": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "[variables('somevar')]"
},
```

1. The same way you are outputting parameters.
2. No there is no way of doing that.

So what is the question, your template looks good. I've tested it and it works

ps. the link on your template is wrong, that's the only thing that doesn't work